# How do I find the root mean squared error of this fit?

Tags: fitting

I have the following data.

```
HSI = {{1.`, 4.502201319666759`}, {2.`, 4.498737206541754`}, {3.`, 
   4.4964025063938955`}, {4.`, 4.491168609823489`}, {5.`, 
   4.480225462058295`}, {6.`, 4.472178038829604`}, {7.`, 
   4.4743675246518775`}, {8.`, 4.4582896838826604`}, {9.`, 
   4.45235342111989`}, {10.`, 4.47731636067876`}, {11.`, 
   4.457492363168564`}, {12.`, 4.465951955374022`}, {13.`, 
   4.464606374521092`}, {14.`, 4.45898605964085`}, {15.`, 
   4.457726468220152`}, {16.`, 4.457199643172643`}, {17.`, 
   4.444311998210321`}, {18.`, 4.450761654864603`}, {19.`, 
   4.436634076088381`}, {20.`, 4.433101795058949`}, {21.`, 
   4.449683071507449`}, {22.`, 4.44430904025694`}, {23.`, 
   4.433387852516324`}, {24.`, 4.425938152412656`}, {25.`, 
   4.421420618879485`}, {26.`, 4.415008417671637`}, {27.`, 
   4.409255990949457`}, {28.`, 4.408889403725628`}, {29.`, 
   4.4067336007306634`}, {30.`, 4.389233972225948`}}
```

I fit it with the following equation.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[HSI, {A + B (t)^z + (c (t)^z)*(Cos[\[Omega]*Log[t] + \[Phi]]), -1 < c < 1, 0.1 <= z <= 0.9, 4.8 <= \[Omega] <= 13, 0 <= \[Phi] <= 2 \[Pi]}, {A, B, z, c, \[Omega], \[Phi]}, t, MaxIterations -> 10000];

fitfun /. nlm["BestFitParameters"];Show[Plot[nlm[t], {t, 1, 30}], ListPlot[HSI]]
```

I get the following fit.

[image]

How do I get the root mean squared error for this fit?

Comment: Do you mean something like (I am using my own data) $${}$$ data = {{1, 2.9}, {2, 5.0}, {3, 7.1}, {4, 8.9}, {5, 10.9}, {6, 
    13.1}, {7, 14.9}, {8, 16.8}, {9, 18.5}, {10, 22.2}}; f[x_] = Fit[data, {1, x}, x];RootMeanSquare[data[[All, 2]] - Map[f, data[[All, 1]]]]?

Comment: `nlm["EstimatedVariance"]^0.5` is the more appropriate estimate for the root mean square for a regression as the denominator is `n` - p` where `n` is the sample size and `p` is the number of estimated parameters.  `RootMeanSquare` just divides by `n`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
HSI = {{1., 4.502201319666759}, {2., 4.498737206541754}, {3., 
    4.4964025063938955}, {4., 4.491168609823489}, {5., 
    4.480225462058295}, {6., 4.472178038829604}, {7., 
    4.4743675246518775}, {8., 4.4582896838826604}, {9., 
    4.45235342111989}, {10., 4.47731636067876}, {11., 
    4.457492363168564}, {12., 4.465951955374022}, {13., 
    4.464606374521092}, {14., 4.45898605964085}, {15., 
    4.457726468220152}, {16., 4.457199643172643}, {17., 
    4.444311998210321}, {18., 4.450761654864603}, {19., 
    4.436634076088381}, {20., 4.433101795058949}, {21., 
    4.449683071507449}, {22., 4.44430904025694}, {23., 
    4.433387852516324}, {24., 4.425938152412656}, {25., 
    4.421420618879485}, {26., 4.415008417671637}, {27., 
    4.409255990949457}, {28., 4.408889403725628}, {29., 
    4.4067336007306634}, {30., 4.389233972225948}};

nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[
   HSI, {A + B t^z + (c t^z)*(Cos[ω*Log[t] + ϕ]), -1 < c < 1, 
    0.1 <= z <= 0.9, 4.8 <= ω <= 13, 0 <= ϕ <= 2 π}, {A, B, z,
     c, ω, ϕ}, t, MaxIterations -> 10000];
```

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) input and use arbitrary-precision by setting [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html)

```
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[
   Rationalize[HSI, 
    0], {A + B t^z + (c t^z)*(Cos[ω*Log[t] + ϕ]), -1 < c < 1, 
    1/10 <= z <= 9/10, 24/5 <= ω <= 13, 0 <= ϕ <= 2 π}, {A, B,
     z, c, ω, ϕ}, t, MaxIterations -> 10000, 
   WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision];
```

**EDIT:** As suggested by @JimB

```
nlm3 = NonlinearModelFit[
   Rationalize[HSI, 
    0], {A + B t^z + (c t^z)*(Cos[ω*Log[t] + ϕ]), -1 < c < 1, 
    1/10 <= z <= 9/10, 24/5 <= ω <= 13, 
    0 <= ϕ <= 2 π}, {{A, 45/10}, {B, -5/100}, {z, 3/10}, {c, 
     1}, {ω, 85/10}, {ϕ, 1}}, t, MaxIterations -> 10000, 
    WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision];
```

Visually comparing the models,

```
Plot[{nlm1[t], nlm2[t], nlm3[t]}, {t, 1, 30},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[HSI]},
 PlotStyle -> {Medium, Medium, Thick},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.8, 0.6}]]
```

[image]

Comment by @Moo showed how to calculate the [`RootMeanSquare`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootMeanSquare.html). Comparing the results,

```
RootMeanSquare[HSI[[All, 2]] - # /@ HSI[[All, 1]]] & /@ {nlm1, nlm2, 
  nlm3}

(* {0.0120219, 0.0107395, 0.00731085} *)
```

indicates that `nlm3` is the better fit (i.e., smaller `RootMeanSquare`).

Comment: Several of the parameter estimators are highly correlated with each other which makes convergence difficult.  If one uses starting values `{{a, 45/10}, {b, -5/100}, {z, 3/10}, {c, 1}, {\[Omega], 85/10}, {\[Phi], 1}}`, then the root mean square is about 30% smaller than what one gets with `nlm2`.

Comment: Uh, sorry.  I changed `A` to `a` and `B` to `b`.  Changing them back to `A` and `B` should make the code work.

Comment: @JimB - added your input. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me beyond what I asked for.

Answer (score 8):

This dataset and model have "issues" because of a few of the parameter estimators being highly correlated with each other.  There are 7 parameters to be estimated:  `A`, `B`, `c`, `z`, `ω`, `ϕ`, and `σ`.  Given `z`, `ω`, `ϕ`, `σ`, we can obtain symbolic estimates of `A`, `B`, and `c` as the problem becomes just a simple linear regression.  Then we can find the estimates of `z`, `ω`, `ϕ`, and `σ`.

```
(* Determine log likelihood *)
data = Rationalize[HSI, 0];
logL = LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[0, σ], (#[[2]] - (a + b #[[1]]^z + (c #[[1]]^z)*
  Cos[ω*Log[#[[1]]] + ϕ]) &) /@ data];

(* Symbolic solution for a, b, and c given σ, ω, ϕ, and z *)
dlogL = D[logL, {{a, b, c}}];
sol = Solve[dlogL == 0, {a, b, c}];

(* Numerically solve for maximum likelihood estimates of σ, ω, ϕ, and z *)
logLs = logL /. sol;
mleωϕzσ = FindMaximum[logLs, {{σ, 7/1000}, {ω, 10}, {ϕ, 0}, {z, 8/10}}]
(* {105.054, {\[Sigma] -> 0.00729368, \[Omega] -> 10.3986, \[Phi] -> -0.580638, z -> 0.924522}} *)

(* Determine maximum likelihood estimates for a, b, and c *)
mleabc = sol /. mleωϕzσ[[2]]
(* {{a -> 4.50173, b -> -0.00402987, c -> 0.000382872}} *)

(* Now get estimate of parameter covariance and correlation matrix *)    
hessian = D[logL, {{a, b, c, z, ω, ϕ, σ}, 2}];
cov = -Inverse[hessian /. mleωϕzσ[[2]] /.  mleabc[[1]]]
cor = Table[cov[[i, j]]/(cov[[i, i]] cov[[j, j]])^0.5, {i, 1, 7}, {j, 1, 7}]
```

Now check of the root mean square:

```
RootMeanSquare[(#[[2]] - (a + b #[[1]]^z + (c #[[1]]^z)*Cos[ω*Log[#[[1]]] + ϕ]) /. 
  mleωϕzσ[[2]] /. mleabc[[1]] &) /@ Rationalize[HSI]]
(* *)
```

This matches with the maximum likelihood estimate of σ and is even a bit smaller than in other answers (0.00729368).

Comment: Why the commas in `cov[[i, i]], cov[[j, j]]` in the definition of cor? Is that a typo?

Comment: @chris Yep, a typo.  Sorry about that.  Thanks for catching that.  I'll edit it.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `RootMeanSquare` on the property `"FitResiduals"`:

```
RootMeanSquare[#["FitResiduals"]] & /@ {nlm1, nlm2, nlm3}
```

> {0.0120112, 0.034652979361999, 0.007328510886305}

where `nlm1`, `nlm2` and `nlm3` are from Bob Hanlon's answer.